# Javascript: Make Object.byString dynamic

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following line of code:

```
for (var t = 0; t < timingobj['Test'].length; t++) {
var test1= "Test[0].NextTest.EstimatedTestScore";

var time= Object.byString(timingobj, test1);
}
```

How do I replace the "0" to be dynamic with "t", using the for loop?
var test1= "Test[t].NextTest.EstimatedTestScore";

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
for (var t = 0; t < timingobj["Test"].length; t++) {
  var test1 = `Test[${t}].NextTest.EstimatedTestScore`;
  var time = Object.byString(timingobj, test1);
}
```